# Sample code to use .NET API for Vimeo

Tags: api, video

I want to use .NET API for Vimeo that has been provided by scommisso.
I am using visual studio 2010. How to complete the authentication process and then search videos and get list of url.
Thanks

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, did you find any?

Comment: APIs provided by scommisso do not support 4.0. These all are provided for 4.5. APIs for visual studios 2010 have been provided for v2 of vimeo API, which is obsolete now. So i have used Official APIs in PHP

Comment: Thanks for the response, i've managed to get the Api working now

Comment: For now all I've done is being able to upload a video, list videos and search for a specific video. Keep in mind using 4.5, you intressted in this? I'm going to play more with it next week.

Comment: I need all the functionality that you have mentioned but problem is i need it for 4.0.

Comment: Dont know how it's done for 4.0, sorry